# Android: Usage of Roboto Light on different screens

Tags: java, android-layout, android, android-fonts

I use the Roboto Light font in a TextView with a TextSize of 14dip. This font is very thin so that why I wonder: Is Roboto Light save to use on all screens (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, tvdpi, xhdpi etc. etc.) or is it not suitable for low-resolution devices?

Answer (score 0):

The correct unit for TextSize is **sp**. Try using it and see if your TextView is okay.

Comment: I'm aware that `sp` is the preferred unit, but using `sp` makes the `TextSize` adaptable by the user and if the user makes the text too big, my layout looks very shitty. That's why I use `dip` instead, which should have the same effect as `sp` except that the size is not adaptable by the user.